# Trying to link a domain to a IP

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I have registered *mydomain.com* now i want to redirect to my IP hosting account.

The DNS editor shows two fields: *Name* and *Address*.

In *Address* i wrote the IP i want the domain redirects.

And in *Name* I wrote *mydomain.com*.

After submitting the form, the page shows this line:

```
Name                  Type     Record   
mydomain.mydomain.com.   A       173.203.58.251
```

I expected it shows this:

```
Name                Type     Record     
mydomain.com.           A    173.203.58.251
```

Is that OK? or am i doing some wrong?

Regards

Javi

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've registered a domain which actually gives you a control on a full zone.

You have full control over the zone mydomain.com, including all it's subdomains.

You actually gave the subdomain mydomain.mydomain.com the IP 173.203.58.251.

You should give the empty subdomain the IP you want so mydomain.com will get it.

It depends on your DNS Editor, but should probably be one of the following (without the quotes):

1. "@" (the at sign)
2. "" (write nothing)
3. "." (one dot)
4. "mydomain.com." (including the last dot)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set the nameservers of the Domain? So that way mydomain.com shows the content from  173.203.58.251?

If so, you are in the wrong control panel. You need to do it in the control panel of the website you bought the domain from.